# ButterKnife and Dagger 2 Conflicts

Tags: android, dagger-2, robolectric, dagger, butterknife

currently have

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"

compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

and as a result my project can't find

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
```

if I switch both dagger statements to use compile it works, but then all of my robolectric tests fail. anyone have any advice ?

Comment: WHy are you using both of these?  Generally you choose one or the other.

Comment: Both of what ?  Each setup is what is recommended by it's documentation

Comment: You don't normally use two injection frameworks. Usually one or the other

Comment: I don't agree that these libraries are similar. `ButterKnife` is view and click listener code generation and `Dagger` is dependency injection library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : Turns out enabling annotationProcessing in the IDE, caused a bunch of stuff to break, but turning it off caused everything to work.

Answer (score 0):

The first remark you have quite outdated dependencies - at least 2.x android gradle plugin makes apt plugin from Hugo as obsolete. Also, Dagger version is near 2.13 now.

These two imports are coming from Guava library which is a transitive dependency to dagger compiler.

So just add `testCompile "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"` and it will be most probably solved unless you will have a clash of Guava versions and you should update resolution strategy for it.